# Return Table C that has_many table B that belongs_to Table A

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three Models:

```rb
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exam_questions,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :question_responses
end

class ExamQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exam_questions
  has_many :question_responses
end
```

With schema:

```rb
create_table "exam_questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "exam_id"
    t.integer  "question_id"
end
```

I know I can do retrieve `exam_questions` out of an exam and loop to get each question, like:

```rb
@exam = Exam.find(params[:id])
@exam_questions = @exam.exam_questions
@exam_questions.find_each do |eq|
  eq.question
end
```

However, I'm trying to get all the questions from an exam. Is there a way to do something like

```rb
@exam = Exam.find(params[:id])
@exam_questions = @exam.exam_questions
@questions = @exam_questions.questions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *exactly* what the [has_many through association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is for. Make your models more like:

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exam_questions,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :exam_questions
  has_many :question_responses
end

class ExamQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exam_questions
  has_many :exams, through: :exam_questions
  has_many :question_responses
end
```

And now you simply do:

```
@exam.questions
```

If you have `@question`, then you can do:

```
@question.exams
```

... to find all the exams that the question is associated with.

I realize it's not included in your question, but that presence of `question_responses` looks suspicious. Off the top of my head, I think I would do something like:

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exam_questions,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :exam_questions
  has_many :exam_question_responses, through: :exam_questions
  has_many :exam_sittings
  has_many :takers, through: :exam_sittings, class_name: 'User'
end

class ExamQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :exam_question_responses
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exam_questions
  has_many :exams, through: :exam_questions
  has_many :exam_question_responses, through: :exam_questions
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exam_sittings
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: exam_question_responses
#
#  id               :bigint           not null, primary key
#  exam_question_id :integer
#  exam_sitting_id  :integer
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
class ExamQuestionResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exam_question
  belongs_to :exam_sitting
end
```

If a `@user` can take a given `@exam` more than once, you might want:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: exam_sittings
#
#  id               :bigint           not null, primary key
#  user_id          :integer
#  exam_id          :integer
#  sat_at           :datetime
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
class ExamSitting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :exam
  has_many :exam_question_responses
end
```

Now you can find which people took a particular exam

```
@exam.takers
```

All the times @user sat for @exam

```
@user.exam_sittings.where(exam: @exam)
```

All the `exam_question_responses` for a particular `@user` on a particular `@exam` on a particular day:

```
@user.exam_sittings.where(exam: @exam, sat_at: some_date)
```

And so on.

This is, quite naturally, incomplete: it seems to me there are other useful associations and scopes to add. These are just some stray thoughts as you head down the road.

Comment: Sure thing! Feel free to accept. Also, I have some additional thoughts about `question_responses` that I'm adding in a moment.